# Reducing row of a matrix with 1 parameter

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}a-2 & 2 & 3 & 0 & -1\\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2(1+a) & 1+a & 3\end{bmatrix}$$

I need to find what values of $a$, there is a single solution, no solution, or infinite solutions for the linear system.

There is no solution if $a=-1$ (from row 3)

And than I continued and got this:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{3}{2(a-2)} & \frac{2a+5}{2(a-2)(a+1)}\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & -\frac{3}{2} & -\frac{3}{2a+2}\\
0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{3}{2a+2}\end{bmatrix}$$

And if I take $2(a-2)(a+1)$ from row 1 ($\frac{2a+5}{2(a-2)(a+1)}$) :

$2(a-2)(a+1)=0 => a=-1, a=2 $

So there is no solution for $a=-1$ **and** $a=2$?

But if I put $a=2$ in the matrix I get a solution.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your elementary row operations are justified only when $a\ne2$ and $a\ne-1$. For these cases you need to perform *different* reductions.

It's clear that in the case of $a=2$ there can be no leading $1$ in column $1$.

When $a=2$, the matrix is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 2 & 3 & 0 & -1\\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 6 & 3 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and the reduced row-echelon form is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
showing the system has infinitely many solutions.

Try for $a=-1$, when the matrix is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-3 & 2 & 3 & 0 & -1\\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The reduction is easy and the system will have no solution.

Comment: Thanks! when I get to the last matrix, I say that there could be two cases? (where a=2 and a!=2) And than I go back to the first matrix and enter the values there?

Comment: I ask because usually from what I learned when I get to a point where $a$ could cause no solution, we branch from there and perform 2 different reductions, but you suggested to go back to the first matrix (if I understand correctly)

Comment: @user356909 I didn't know what elimination steps you did, so I performed the reduction from start. But, in general, you can certainly go back to the step where a "division by a coefficient" is illicit for a particular value of the parameter and do the substitution there.